# Apache: Copied files from another directory do not work

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, cp, directoryindex

I recently set up my Apache server (2.2) with PHP (5.3) on my Oracle Linux computer.  Initially, I created three files: `index.html`, `index.php`, and `countries.html`.  I believe (do not recall 100%) that I created these files in my `/var/www/html/` folder, and these files were automatically given  **root**  permissions for both owner and group.  However, when I copied my `index.html` into my home directory (not root), I was no longer able to access the file (403 Message - Forbidden access), even after I moved it back into it's original `/var/www/html/` folder and changed its permissions for owner and group back into  **root**.

Notably, my `index.php` file was the default page, even though it wasn't listed in the `DirectoryIndex`.  Furthermore, I experimented with my `index.php` file by copying it, deleting the original, moving the copied version back into the `/var/www/html/` folder, and changing the permissions.  Same result, where it didn't work.  Only difference is that the php file threw an internal server error (HTTP Error 500).

I have added my `countries.html` file into my `DirectoryIndex` line, and it will now display as the default page.  However, if I remove it and leave my `DirectoryIndex` line as it is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
```

then it will default to my `index.php` page and output the internal server error.

Right now, I see a couple of problems:

1. The copied files do not work, despite having the same permissions.  I believe my experiment with copying the `index.php` file is proof of this.
2. The default page, which was `index.php`, is not listed in the `DirectoryIndex`, yet it still is the default.

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen in case when you are using old php version and in your php file there is some syntax related to new php version. As in php 5.3 we don't have short array notation but in 5.5 we have also in 5.4 i guess that also can gives internal server error.

See your php version by

```
php -v
```

and if its version 5.3 or less check your php file if contains any new things like new short array notation [].

Don't know am i talking in the same context in which you want. As i didn't understand the question very well.

Comment: Not too sure what this short array notation is supposed to be.  Is this an option in the php.ini file?  Or is this more of a syntax used within the file?

Comment: It is new array declaration syntax.Earlier we used to do $arr = array().
Now we can also do $arr = [].